# How to convert this Entity Framework query to a SQL Server query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a query which is written in format like this:

```
bool filterQuotes = false;
bool filterInactive = false;
var res = await DbContext.CheckPlans
                .Where(plan => plan.PlanID == currentPlanId)
                .SelectMany(plan => plan.CheckActivityPlanDetail)
                .Include(planDetail => planDetail.CheckActivity)
                .ThenInclude(checkActivity => checkActivity.Setup)
                .Where(planDetail => (!filterQuotes || planDetail.CheckActivity.ActivityType==0)
                    && (!filterInactive || planDetail.IsActive))
                .OrderBy(planDetail => planDetail.CheckActivity.Setup.Value)
                .ToListAsync();
```

How do I convert this query to a plain SQL Server query to see what its output is?

Comment: Do you want to see the SQL this query generates, or do you want SQL equivalent to this EF query?

Comment: The SQL query it generates.

Comment: Are you using EF or EF Core?

Comment: @trashr0x EF core.
I have very little idea of how these methods are written, if anyone could point me out to the documentation to refer, that would be really awesome

Comment: Do you try use SQL profiler to catch SQL query after execute?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Entity Framework there are a few ways to look at the SQL a query generates.

**Note:** All these ways will use this query:

```cs
var query = DbContext.CheckPlans
                .Where(plan => plan.PlanID == currentPlanId)
                .SelectMany(plan => plan.CheckActivityPlanDetail)
                .Include(planDetail => planDetail.CheckActivity)
                .ThenInclude(checkActivity => checkActivity.Setup)
                .Where(planDetail => (!filterQuotes || planDetail.CheckActivity.ActivityType==0)
                    && (!filterInactive || planDetail.IsActive))
                .OrderBy(planDetail => planDetail.CheckActivity.Setup.Value);
```

1. Cast `IQueryable` to an `ObjectQuery` and get it's trace string:

```cs
// ObjectQuery is in the 'System.Data.Objects' namespace if EF version < 6
// starting with EF version 6 and upwards it's in the 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects' namespace
var sql = ((ObjectQuery) query).ToTraceString();
```

2. Intercept logging and print it to `Debug.WriteLine`:

```cs
// This code needs to be placed where you are creating your DbContext
context.Database.Log = s => Debug.WriteLine(s);

// ...
// Then when executing the query with
var results = query.ToListAsync();
// Your debug console in Visual Studio should contain all the information you need
```

3. Entity Framework configuration.
   If you're using EF 6.1 an onwards, you can use the EF configuration to create an interceptor and log it to a txt file as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/configuring/config-file?redirectedfrom=MSDN#interceptors-ef61-onwards):

```xml
<interceptors>
  <interceptor type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DatabaseLogger, EntityFramework">
    <parameters>
      <parameter value="C:\Temp\LogOutput.txt"/>
      <parameter value="true" type="System.Boolean"/>
    </parameters>
  </interceptor>
</interceptors>
```

4. And lastly, you could use [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net/). There's a free version that can connect to a database, and where you can directly enter C# expressions or statements and have the generated SQL show up at the bottom, similar to this [image: Screenshot of LinqPad 6]

Answer (score 0):

The DbContext.Database.Log property can be set to a delegate for any method that takes a string. In this example the SQL statements are written to the console with Console.Write

```
using (var context = new BlogContext())
{
    context.Database.Log = Console.Write;
    var blog = context.Blogs.First(b => b.Title == "One Unicorn");
    blog.Posts.First().Title = "Green Eggs and Ham";
    blog.Posts.Add(new Post { Title = "I do not like them!" });
    context.SaveChangesAsync().Wait();
}
```

From: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/logging-and-interception